# Error while trying to convert a .tif file to jpg: A generic error occurred in GDI+

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to convert a .tif file to .jpg but I get the following exception:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.ExternalException: A generic error occurred in GDI+.
```

I'm running this on a Windows 10 machine.

How can I fix this error?

This is my program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Encoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder;

namespace Test
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SaveAsJpeg(@"C:\Temp\Target\test_converted.jpg", 70);

            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) return;
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to quit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static FileInfo SaveAsJpeg(string newFilePath, long quality)
        {
            // File to convert
            var path = @"C:\Temp\test.tif";

            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
            {
                using (var imageToConvert = Image.FromStream(stream))
                {
                    // This line throws the error
                    imageToConvert.Save(newFilePath, GetDecoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), GetQualityEncoderParameters(quality));
                }
            }

            return new FileInfo(newFilePath);
        }

        private static ImageCodecInfo GetDecoder(ImageFormat format)
        {
            var codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageDecoders();
            return codecs.FirstOrDefault(codec => codec.FormatID == format.Guid);
        }

        private static EncoderParameters GetQualityEncoderParameters(long quality)
        {
            var qualityParameter = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality);
            var encoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1) { Param = { [0] = qualityParameter } };
            return encoderParameters;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I have...

- Made sure that `C:\Temp\Target` exists
- Made sure that `Everyone` have full read/write access to `C:\Temp\Target`

These are the file properties:

[image]

[image]

Edit:

After trying the same code with a different image, and no errors were thrown, there's probably an issue with the image i'm trying to convert. An image with the following properties is successfully converted:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you eliminated the file itself as the cause? I.e does this work with something simple like a .bmp?

Comment: Hey Marcus, I just tried your code on both a windows 7 machine and windows 10 machine. It worked on both. Since you stated that you made sure the Target folder exists, I think that @AlexK. is correct. The problem could be within the picture itself. Make sure that it exists, try to open it normally in Photos or some other application. It might even be corrupted.

Comment: @AlexK.Interesting. I tried with a different image (also a tif, a bit smaller dimensions but the same bit depth, DPI and compression) and that worked. Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Comment: Is it loadable with Image.FromFile()?  If that fails I think it would be safe to assume there is something wrong with the file (does it open in other apps?) or it contains some feature that is not supported by the GDI TIFF codec.  LibTiff.Net is an alternative library it may be worth looking at should that be the case.

Comment: @AlexK. Yea, Image.FromFile() works (but still throws the GDI+ error) and I can open the image in other apps.

Comment: Does it change anything if you replace Image.FromFile by new Bitmap(stream) ?

Comment: @Isma almost, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how, but this seems to do the trick. No errors are thrown, and the image is converted successfully:

```
public static FileInfo SaveAsJpeg(string newFilePath, long quality)
{
    var path = @"C:\Temp\test.tif";

    using (var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path)))
    {
        var imageToConvert = Image.FromStream(stream); 
        using (imageToConvert = new Bitmap(imageToConvert))
        {
            imageToConvert.Save(newFilePath, GetDecoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg), GetQualityEncoderParameters(quality));
        }
    }

    return new FileInfo(newFilePath);
}
```

If anyone could elaborate on why this works, that would be great.